# Not able to find images and files

Tags: angular6, playframework-2.6

My `Angular` application is served by `Play` server. The application can't find images and fonts I have added in the component when I build the application and run it.

The images are accessed in the component.html as follows

```
<div id="nav" class="nav-style nav-flexbox-container">
    <img id="stats-icon-pic" src="assets/images/StatsIcon.png">
    <img id="mail-icon-pic" src="assets/images/MailIcon.png">
    <img id="profile-pic" src="assets/images/ExampleProfilePic.png">
  </div>
```

The fonts are used as

```
@font-face{
  font-family:"solway-bold";
  src:url(../../assets/fonts/solway/fonts/Solway-Bold.ttf);
}
```

the images and fonts are in the assets folder in Angular application

[image]

When I build the application, I use the public folder of `Play` as output directory.

```
"build": "ng build --output-path ../public/ui",
```

I am facing two issues

1) The application can't find the images and fonts

[image]

I see the following error message on my `Play` application

```
[trace] u.CustomHttpErrorHandler - client error: request GET /assets/images/ExampleLogo.png, statusCode: 404, message:Resource not found by Assets controller
[trace] u.CustomHttpErrorHandler - client error: request GET /assets/images/MailIcon.png, statusCode: 404, message:Resource not found by Assets controller
[trace] u.CustomHttpErrorHandler - client error: request GET /assets/images/ExampleProfilePic.png, statusCode: 404, message:Resource not found by Assets controller
[trace] u.CustomHttpErrorHandler - client error: request GET /assets/images/StatsIcon.png, statusCode: 404, message:Resource not found by Assets controller
[trace] u.CustomHttpErrorHandler - client error: request GET /Solway-ExtraBold.ttf, statusCode: 404, message:
[trace] u.CustomHttpErrorHandler - client error: request GET /Solway-Light.ttf, statusCode: 404, message:
```

I changed the path of images in `src` to `ui/assets/images/StatsIcon.png` but still get error `client error: request GET /ui/assets/images/StatsIcon.png, statusCode: 404, message:`

2) the font files are copied both in the `ui/assets/fonts/...` folder as well as the top level `ui/assets/` folder. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not due to `Angular` but due to my incorrect usage in `play` framework. `Play` has a route rule

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

The above means that all the requests for resources with path `/assets/abc/def` should be taken from the folder `/public/abc/def`. In my case the resources are at /public/ui/assets/images`. So I had to change the`src`in the Angular`html`to``. This makes requests with path`assets/ui/assets/images/example-logo.png`which gets mapped to the path`public/ui/assets/images/example-logo.png`